# how to subtract 1 from all array elements in perl

Tags: perl

I have an array which contains values. I need to subtract 1 from each array elements & save there itself.

For Example:

```
chop $tve_005;
@words = split (/,/, $tve_005);
```

and now `@words` contains:

```
524210
1713409
311919
1422134
16658312
```

But infact values need to be used in the rest of the codes are: (subtract by 1 always)

```
524209
1713408
311918
1422133
16658311
```

How can I subtract and save it the same array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @words = (524210,1713409,311919,1422134,16658312);

@words = map { $_ - 1 } @words;
```

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively to Pradeep's solution, some characters shorter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @words = (524210,1713409,311919,1422134,16658312);

$_-- for @words;
```